# Problems setting up an SQL User-Defined Function in MySQL using the Java Language

Tags: java, mysql, plugins, user-defined-functions

I have had quite some difficulty trying to make a User Defined Function (UDF) in Java for my MySQL Server. I was hoping I could ask for some help on this subject.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have followed the instructions [on a Planet MySQL post](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=13420) but I fear that it may be outdated, as the plugin files do not contain a psm_java.so file which was expected to exist in the tutorial.

I need to implement the Levenshtein distance in Java given two strings so that I can return that value back. I know how to do that part, but I have not been able to do the SQL interaction part.

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

System information:

Mac OS X 10.7.2
MySQL 5.5.16

Comment: If it matters...I did this about 2 years ago (I used a C udf) and found it wasn't that fast. I then tried Approximate String Joins, and they weren't that fast either. For me, pulling the result set into the JEE container and doing the Levenshtein there was faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a project assignment that requires me to process the data in this fashion.

Comment: How would I go about doing it in C? I am on my mac, and all the tutorials seem to point to Visual C++ as being necessary in order to proceed.

Comment: Do you have to use Levenshtein or will Jaro Winkler (btw.. I think Jaro is better) work?

Comment: Unfortunately, the requirements are to compute the Levenshtein distance, and only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go outside the RDBMS? You can implement the [Levenshtein distance in a MySQL UDF](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for this! My requirements are to do it in C or C++, but I appreciate this.